# Sails.js populate with where

Tags: sails.js, waterline, populate

I need to select users with dogs (pets with `type` equal 'dog')

```
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'user',

  attributes: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',

    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
});

var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  identity: 'pet',

  attributes: {
    type: 'string',
    name: 'string',

    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
});
```

I didn't find any examples, I tried like this

```
User.find().populate('pets', {type: 'dog'}).exec(err, users) ...
```

and this

```
User.find().where({'pets.type': 'dog'}).populate('pets').exec(err, users) ...
```

but that does not work

Would be greate if result users array will has no pets records

Comment: are you going to filter users, or is your only filter ```pet.type = dog```?

Comment: any proposal which resolve this issue by using Waterline (not raw query) will be good, only `pet.type = dog` too

Answer (score 6):

Did you try this?

```
User.find().populate('pets', {
  where: {
    type: 'dog'
  }
}).exec(err, users)...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to query users and just need the query for dogs. You could just as easily reverse the query.

`Pet.find({type: 'dog'}).populate('users').exec(err, petsWithUsers)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for hasn't been implemented in waterline (Sails ORM) yet, check [issue #266](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/266) for more details.

> `User.find().populate('pets', {type: 'dog'}).exec(err, users) ...`

This will return all users (`User.find()`) and only populate pets of type dog (`populate('pets', {type: 'dog'})`). So you'll have users without dogs in your results.

> User.find().where({'pets.type': 'dog'}).populate('pets').exec(err, users) ...

Waterline does not support dot (.) notation. Sails-mongo does have some support for it due to [MongoDB support](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

Finally, if you are using one of the SQL adapters you may work around this by doing a raw sql query using `.query()` ([docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/67545664138e7362640756dd97205142cc72cac9/query-methods.md#query-query-data-callback-)).