# sails js mongodb populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I would like to use .populate() with Sails js and MongoDB and so I did something like this:

I am using the latest version of Sails and MongoDB and Node.

My models look like:

```
// User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
};
```

```
// Pet.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
};
```

And I used the following which is the same as the documentation:

```
User.find()
.populate('pets')
.exec(function(err, users) {
  if(err) return res.serverError(err);
  res.json(users);
});
```

But I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "pets": [],
    "id": "58889ce5959841098d186b5a",
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Bar"
  }
]
```

Comment: Made an issue: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/449

Comment: in config/model.js ensure that you have `migrate: 'safe'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the query for dogs. You could just as easily reverse the query.

```
Pet.find() //or what you want with {}
 .populate('users')
 .exec(err, petsWithUsers)
```

But if not:

```
User.find()
      .populate('pets')
      .exec(err, users) ...
```

This will return all users (`User.find()`) and only populate pets of type dog (`populate('pets', {type: 'dog'})`). In the case you'll have users without dogs in your results.

More information and Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225945/sails-js-populate-with-where)