# How do I get set of records based on associated collection limited to populate exclusive criteria?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Using Waterline (and Sails.js) how do I query for results of a many to many association limited exclusively to matching the entire criteria set?

```
Room.find({type:"1to1"}).populate('participants', { id: [ 1, 2] }).
then((rooms)=>{
   // rooms array of records should only contain room records
   // that have both participants with an id of 1 and 2,
   // but not rooms with only one participant 1 or 2
})
```

I am looking for the result to only contain `rooms` that have both specified users.

Comment: Probably duplicate question check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225945/sails-js-populate-with-where

Comment: Not implemented yet check this one https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/266